# System claims AVX2 is supported, but broadcasts of integer registers are unimplemented

Tags: x86, avx2, illegal-instruction

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` reports that the avx2 flag is set.

However, the AVX2 instruction vpbroadcastb causes an illegal instruction exception when ran.

I am using x86_64 Linux and nasm as my assembler. On my system, reproducing this is as simple as

```
global main
main:
vpbroadcastb xmm1, eax
```

using NASM.

Anyone know anything about this? This is a AMD A12-9700P RADEON R7 APU that i'm using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`vpbroadcastb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPBROADCAST.html) with a general purpose register as operand requires AVX512.  It assembles (with a new enough assembler), but you get an *illegal instruction* signal on CPUs with only AVX2.

If your CPU supports AVX2,

```
vpbroadcastb xmm1, xmm0
```

for example, should work.

Comment: The link you've provided is for `vpbroadcast`, not `vpbroadcastb`, which can actually use a GPR. However, `vpbroadcastb` is an AVX512 instruction.

Comment: The link covers several vpbroadcast* instructions and mentions VEX128-encoded vpbroadcastb being AVX2. On my server, which happens to support AVX2 but not AVX512, [`vpbroadcastb xmm1, eax`](https://tio.run/##JcZRCoAgDADQf0@xAxjoX3SZ2EoicBpuyDq9BX69hyKJKb9LQeExrlwJM@yi2NRNNtcfahXPA0UJjDl6SGiOa4dE5iHM4t/o7qIQbA1jfA) does error, but [`vpbroadcastb xmm1, xmm0`](https://tio.run/##LcbBCYAwDEDRe6fIAArtTVxGEi0iNK00odTpo6KX/x@KRKZ0jRmFzfZUCBMsoljVfZtdO6kW3FYUJejMYXjrHZcGkfoAP/FhcEdW8H3yZjc) does not.

Comment: There is a version of `vpbroadcastb` (`EVEX.128.66.0F38.W0 7A`) part of AVX512 that does work with a GPR. I think the assembler is producing that version, which is causing an illegal instruction exception because AVX512 is not supported.

Comment: @HadiBrais: There's no `vpbroadcast`, the page title is generic.  But yes, the reason `vpbroadcastb xmm1, eax` assembles at all is because there's an AVX512 EVEX encoding for it, @dennis.  An older *assembler* that doesn't know about AVX512 at all (for example YASM) will say `error: invalid size for operand 2`.

Comment: Fun fact: AVX1 broadcast instructions can only broadcast from memory, like `vbroadcastss xmm1, [my_constant]`.  AVX2 is required for `vbroadcastss x/ymm1, xmm0` (an ALU shuffle instead of a broadcast-load that runs in a load port), even though it's the same opcode for vbroadcastss ymm1, xmm/m32`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. The answer before you edited it said "you're getting an exception because `vpbroadcastb` does not work with a GPR", but the assembler is using the version of the instruction that *does* use a GPR but it requires AVX512 support. So the reason for the exception is that the CPU does not support AVX512, not that `vpbroadcastb` does not accept a GPR. After you edited the answer, it has become correct.